# Change size constantly in css transition

Tags: css, pixel

I have made a div id in my html, and in my div there is an image.
now i would like to have that my image becomes the size bigger and smaller, and 
that constantly. Has anybody an idea how to do that, i prefer css.
This is my css but the image only scales when you hover, but I want to scale it automatically.

```
#fotohart{
position: absolute;
margin-top: 75px;
margin-left: 483px;
- webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

#fotohart:hover{
-webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with "my image becomes the size bigger and smaller, and that constantly"? Can you show an example of what you want?

Comment: do you want it to grow and shrink the whole time? Like pulse?

Comment: i would like that the image constantly scales, not only when you hover. I mean like a heart that is beating....

Comment: Judging from the ID I'd sat a pulse is what is required.

Comment: take a look at "infinite" state for transitions!